# jmeter session: wrong credentials ()

Tags: cookies, jmeter, session-cookies

I have a jmeter test plan that runs well when I access my own development machine.
When I move to a staging server with the application, I always get no session errors, it means I can't make a request to an authenticated page while running the test on my staging server.
I thought it was problem with the cookie manager, but I tried to switch between all of the cookie  policies and got nothing better.

I don't know where I can check anymore, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your structure, i can only tell you what you need to look into. My last test's authentication was something like this:

```
-CSV Data Config (contains csv with username and password)
-HTTP Request (Login page)
   Response Assertion (which makes sure that session exists)
   Regular Expression Extractor (find Session ID and set it to a variable) 
-...
```

If you can post your structure, I may help you a little more.